# Avoid repository creation on typo

Tags: git, gitolite

I've setup a gitolite server in my company : works great, but most of the time i spend to administer it consist in deleting repository created by mistake.
Indeed, users have access to a projects root directory in which they can create repositories for their projects, using the concept of *wild repo* :

> You do not have to do anything special to create such a repo; just clone it as if it already existed, and it will spring into existence.

(http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/01/gitolite-specify-complex-access-controls-git-server/)

I would prefer if cloning and creating were mapped to two different commands to avoid such unintentional repo creation.
Is there a best practice to achieve such a workflow ?

Comment: Look up the `no-auto-create` and `no-create-on-read` features in your `.gitolite.rc` file.

Answer (score 2):

> I would prefer if cloning and creating were mapped to two different commands

This doesn't seem possible when you consider that the only way to clone a repo is for that repo to exist first.
That means a user will clone a repo created in the background by Gitolite (because of the [wild repo directive](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/wild.html))

However, deleting a repo should be very easy for an admin, considering **[Gitolite commands](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/cust.html#commands)** ([Stefan Näwe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/181986/stefan-nawe) details [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905081/avoid-repository-creation-on-typo/21907132?noredirect=1#comment33193875_21907132)):

```
#  move it into the trashcan (can be restored) 
ssh git@host D trash repo

# Or, to really delete it
ssh git@host D unlock repo
ssh git@host D rm repo
```

If anything you could setup some cron job which would monitor each repository content, and on seeing a particular file in it (like '`TO_DELETE`') would delete the repo.
You can add other criteria in order to prevent the deletion of a legitiate repo (ie one with a lots of commits and recent activity).
that way, all a user would have to delete a repo he/she just created would be to add a '`TO_DELETE`' file, commit and push.

Comment: There are two ways to delete a repo: 1. `ssh git@host D trash repo` to move it into the trashcan (can be restored) 2. `ssh git@host D unlock repo; ssh git@host D rm repo` to really delete it.

Comment: @StefanNäwe Thank you for the exact syntax, I have included it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [Stefan Näwe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/181986/stefan-nawe) for mentioning the `no-auto-creat` pref that put me on the right track.
After checking the [gitolite changelog](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/CHANGELOG) it appears that the `create` command does exist since the v3.3 (needs to be explicitely activated though).

Upgrading my gitolite install and combining these two features seems to be the solution.

Comment: +1. Don't hesitate to edit your answer to detail how you used the `create` command and `no-auto-create` setting.